# Hawkular Metrics not be brought to Grafana web console

Tags: grafana, hawkular

My OS is CentOS 7 and running Wildfly 10.1 on it. The monitoring tools are Hawkular 0.39.0 and Grafana server 3.1.1. I modify the specific IP of Hawkular and Wildfly. Below are the log contents

Hawkular

```
18:19:01,601 INFO  [org.hawkular.metrics.core.dropwizard.MetricsInitializer] (RxComputationScheduler-1) Finished creating metrics in 702 ms
18:19:01,721 WARN  [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster] (cluster2-worker-0) Re-preparing already prepared query is generally an anti-pattern and will likely affect performance. Consider preparing the statement only once. Query='SELECT DISTINCT tenant_id, tname FROM metrics_tags_idx'
18:19:01,803 INFO  [org.hawkular.metrics.core.util.GCGraceSecondsManager] (metricsservice-lifecycle-thread) Checking tables in hawkular_metrics to see if gc_grace_seconds needs to be updated
18:19:01,811 INFO  [org.hawkular.metrics.api.jaxrs.MetricsServiceLifecycle] (metricsservice-lifecycle-thread) HAWKMETRICS200005: Metrics service started
18:19:01,830 INFO  [org.hawkular.metrics.core.util.GCGraceSecondsManager] (RxComputationScheduler-3) Finished gc_grace_seconds updates in 26 ms
18:19:02,081 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.cmd.FeedCommProcessor] (Hawkular Java Agent Start Thread) HAWKMONITOR010039: The command-gateway URL is [ws://192.168.200.51:8080/hawkular/command-gateway/feed/localhost]
18:19:02,148 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.scheduler.SchedulerService] (Hawkular Java Agent Start Thread) HAWKMONITOR010012: Starting scheduler
18:19:02,148 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.cmd.FeedCommProcessor] (OkHttp http://192.168.200.51:8080/...) HAWKMONITOR010034: Opened feed WebSocket connection to endpoint [ws://192.168.200.51:8080/hawkular/command-gateway/feed/localhost]
18:19:02,195 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (default-threads - 4) AMQ151000: awaiting topic/queue creation HawkularQueue
18:19:02,200 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.protocol.ProtocolServices] (Hawkular Java Agent Start Thread) HAWKMONITOR010019: Managed server [Local DMR] is disabled. It will not be monitored.
18:19:02,228 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (default-threads - 2) AMQ151000: awaiting topic/queue creation HawkularCommandEvent
18:19:02,239 INFO  [org.hawkular.cmdgw.command.ws.server.FeedWebSocket] (default task-7) HAWKFEEDCOMM000013: WebSocket session [localhost] opened for endpoint [/feed/{feedId}]
18:19:02,328 INFO  [org.xnio] (Hawkular Java Agent Start Thread) XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
```

Wildfly 10.1

```
18:18:55,599 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 11438ms - Started 894 of 1172 services (470 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
18:18:55,603 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.service.AgentCoreEngine] (Hawkular WildFly Agent Startup Thread) HAWKMONITOR010084: Hawkular Agent: WildFly Agent Subsystem version 1.0.0.CR6
18:18:55,632 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.service.AgentCoreEngine] (Hawkular WildFly Agent Startup Thread) HAWKMONITOR010000: Starting Hawkular Agent
18:18:55,632 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.service.MonitorService] (Hawkular WildFly Agent Startup Thread) HAWKMONITOR020059: Agent is using storage adapter mode [HAWKULAR]
18:18:55,632 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.service.MonitorService] (Hawkular WildFly Agent Startup Thread) HAWKMONITOR020050: Tenant ID [hawkular]
18:18:55,654 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.service.MonitorService] (Hawkular WildFly Agent Startup Thread) HAWKMONITOR020025: Will talk to Hawkular at URL [http://192.168.200.51:8080]
18:19:06,777 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.cmd.FeedCommProcessor] (Hawkular WildFly Agent Startup Thread) HAWKMONITOR010039: The command-gateway URL is [ws://192.168.200.51:8080/hawkular/command-gateway/feed/51491521-cdcb-4d11-9869-676b06491c8e]
18:19:06,793 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.cmd.FeedCommProcessor] (OkHttp http://192.168.200.51:8080/...) HAWKMONITOR010034: Opened feed WebSocket connection to endpoint [ws://192.168.200.51:8080/hawkular/command-gateway/feed/51491521-cdcb-4d11-9869-676b06491c8e]
18:19:06,803 INFO  [org.hawkular.agent.monitor.scheduler.SchedulerService] (Hawkular WildFly Agent Startup Thread) HAWKMONITOR010012: Starting scheduler
```

On Grafana Web console, I add hawkular plugin with this command

```
# grafana-cli plugins install hawkular-datasource
```

And hawkular 0.39 is attached to Grafana web console successfully.

[image]

However when I make dashboard with Hawkular plugin, any metrics of Hawkular will not be brought to Grafana server.

[image]

[image]

Do I miss any process of Hawkular Monitoring with Grafana?

### Updated

I am afraid there show no metrics titles like below pictures

[image]

But the below picture shows that http://192.168.200.51:8080/hawkular/metrics site gives the successful metrics

[image]

Any idea? Now I will format my Centos 7 again and reinstall all applications.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand if you are expecting pre-populated dashboard, but it is not the case: it's up to you to build the dashboard you want with the collected metrics. Can you check if some metrics are suggested when you click on "-- none --" next to "Metric name"? There should be the wildfly metrics.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Pls, check my ==Updated== part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshots you set `test` for the tenant in the datasource config panel.

Try to set it to `hawkular` (which is the default in the Hawkular Wildfly agent), then you should see some metrics.